# appSplit does not work when I add a page / view using SAPui5

Tags: sapui5

**MESSAGE AND CODE, EDITED**
I followed this tutorial "**Navigate between single full view and split view**", to add a separate page / view of the appSplit and now it works perfectly, but now I have the following problem, and that is that the "create" target of the "split" throws me this error in the console.

> The target create has no controlId set and no parent so the target
>   cannot be displayed. - EventProvider sap.m.routing.Target

I can not create a new user anymore, because of this error, the "NotFound" target does not work either

**This is the code of my Router**

```
"routing": {
    "config": {
        "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
        "viewType": "XML",
        "viewPath": "Apptest.view",
        "controlAggregation": "pages",
        "clearTarget": "false",
        "bypassed": {
            "target": [
                "notFound"
            ]
        },
        "async": true
    },
    "routes": [
        {
            "pattern": "",
            "name": "LaunchPad",
            "view": "LaunchPad",
            "targetControl": "customFioriContent"
        },

        {
            "pattern": "split",
            "name": "App",
            "view": "App",
            "targetControl": "customFioriContent",
            "subroutes": [
                {
                    "pattern": "master",
                    "name": "master",
                    "view": "Master",
                    "targetAggregation": "masterPages",
                    "preservePageInSplitContainer": true,
                    "targetControl": "fioriContent",
                    "subroutes": [
                        {
                            "pattern": "object/{SUC_ID}",
                            "name": "object",
                            "view": "Detail",
                            "targetAggregation": "detailPages"
                        }
                    ]
                }

            ]
        }
    ],
    "targets": {
        "master": {
            "viewName": "Master",
            "viewLevel": 2,
            "viewId": "master",
            "controlAggregation": "masterPages"
        },
        "LaunchPad": {
            "viewName": "LaunchPad",
            "controlAggregation": "pages",
            "viewId": "LaunchPad",
            "viewLevel": 1
        },
        "object": {
            "viewName": "Detail",
            "viewId": "detail",
            "viewLevel": 3
        },
        "objectNotFound": {
            "viewName": "ObjectNotFound",
            "viewId": "objectNotFound"
        },
        "notFound": {
            "viewName": "NotFound",
            "viewId": "notFound"
        },
        "detailObjectNotFound": {
            "viewName": "DetailObjectNotFound",
            "viewId": "detailObjectNotFound",
            "controlAggregation": "pages"
        },
        "detailNoObjectsAvailable": {
            "viewName": "DetailNoObjectsAvailable",
            "viewId": "detailNoObjectsAvailable"
        },
        "SplitApp": {
            "viewType": "XML",
            "viewName": "SplitApp"
        },
        "create": {
            "viewName": "CreateEntity",
            "viewLevel": 2
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, that the *launchpad* is just an independent page that will take you to the split app, you don't need to define the *controlAggregation* for the launchpad Route. Just remove  *controlAggregation": "pages"* and it should work.

Also remove the  "controlAggregation": "detailPages", from the config on the "config" area of your json.

Comment: I updated my answer. You need to remove the  "controlAggregation": "detailPages",  on the "config" area of your json.

Comment: i have this error on press "create" event
The target create has no controlId set and no parent so the target cannot be displayed. - EventProvider sap.m.routing.Target